# How to create group alphabet gridview devexpress?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Can any one help me to create group alphabet gridview to look like this picture?
I've tried with this code, but rows are not grouped by alphabet.

```
Private Sub GridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(sender As Object, e As CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText
    If e.Column.FieldName = "CompanyName" AndAlso e.IsForGroupRow Then
        Dim rowValue As String = GridView1.GetGroupRowValue(e.GroupRowHandle, e.Column) 
        Dim val As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(rowValue, 1) 
        e.DisplayText = val
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: group alpabet gridview devexpress]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with rows NOT grouped by alphabet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to handle the CustomColumnDisplay text event handler to extract the first letter of the "CompanyName" value. Instead, simply set the [GridColumn.GroupInterval property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_GroupIntervaltopic) for the "CompanyName" GridColumn to "[Alphabetical](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGridColumnGroupIntervalEnumtopic)". For instance:

```
MyGridView.Columns("CompanyName").GroupInterval = ColumnGroupInterval.Alphabetical
```